# libgdx ScreenShot Photo Damaged

Tags: opengl, libgdx

My screenshot photo cant be opened, written "appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large." when open with windows photo viewer in desktop. However, i do able to see my created texture (from `getFullTexture()` function) in game. Anyone please help.

My codes as follow:

```
 public static Texture getFullTexture(){
    if(Gdx.app.getGraphics().getGLVersion().isVersionEqualToOrHigher(2,0))
    {
        Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), Pixmap.Format.RGB888);

        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        Gdx.gl.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        texture.bind();
        Gdx.gl.glCopyTexImage2D(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL20.GL_RGB, 0, 0,Constant.REAL_DEVICE_WIDTH, Constant.REAL_DEVICE_HEIGHT, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        return texture;
    }
}


public static void saveImage(Texture photoTexture){
    try{
        if (!photoTexture.getTextureData().isPrepared()) {
            photoTexture.getTextureData().prepare();
        }
        Pixmap pixmap = photoTexture.getTextureData().consumePixmap();
        FileHandle fh;

        do{
            fh = new FileHandle(Gdx.files.getExternalStoragePath() + "test.jpg");
        }while (fh.exists());
        PixmapIO.writePNG(fh, pixmap);
        pixmap.dispose();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

I tried my saveImage() function with other texture and have no error. Only not workable with the texture from getFullTexture() function.

My main use of code:

```
ScreenShotFactory.saveImage(getFullTexture());
```

Comment: Are `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `Constant.REAL_DEVICE_WIDTH` different values?

Comment: Nope. Both are the same.

Comment: The PNG format uses transparency (jpg doesnt). I don't know if `PixmapIO.writePNG` or `consumePixmap()` can add the Alpha channel. What happens if ypou change the *internalFormat* parameter of `Texture` and `glCopyTexImage2D` from RGB to RGBA?

Comment: Tested with changing Texture format from `Pixmap.Format.RGB888 > Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888`, glCopyTexImage2D  from `GL20.GL_RGB > GL20.GL_RGBA`, directories `test.jpg > test.png`. But still no luck :(.     ++ Tested creating png image with writePNG method has no error with other images.